Что должно быть в скобках после функции
я занимаюсь программированием приличное время, но никогда не задумывался зачем после функции в скобках что-то указывать
Я знаю что в математике просто есть аргумент, но пожалуй я как-то не могу связать с кодом это
private void addUserControl(UserControl userControl)
{
    userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    PanelContainer.Controls.Clear();
    PanelContainer.Controls.Add(userControl);
    userControl.BringToFront();
}

Тут я понимаю, что делаю с юзерконтролем,но зачем в скобках я писал по 2 раза одно и тоже? (Делал по гайду на ютубе)
Был бы рад если вы объясните, для чего нужно там писать что-либо и в каких случаях я могу оставить скобки пустыми

зачем в скобках я писал по 2 раза одно и тоже? - о чем конкретно идет речь? Я вижу в скобках один параметр, не более. На данный момент я ваш вопрос не понимаю.

@EvgeniyZ там 2 слова ) как я понимаю, это же типизация?

private void addUserControl(UserControl userControl)
Есть UserControl  с большой и с маленькой буквы, VS говорит что это просто элемент, а userControl уже параметр, зачем вот их в скобки? Почему я не могу без них?

Если речь идет про 2 слова, то тогда странно видеть такой вопрос, в котором еще сказано "занимаюсь программированием приличное время". Это стандартные аргументы метода, где передается тип и имя, по которому потом идет обращение к данному объекту. В C# строгая типизация, где вы обязаны указать как тип, так и имя объекта в параметрах (если вам параметр конечно нужен).

Я занимался раньше не используя это практически, примерно года 1-2 как хобби, а разве я не могу просто обращаться без назывании - UserControl.DockStyle ...

"года 1-2" и не знаете что такое объекты и методы... Для меня это, странно. я не могу просто обращаться без назывании - если у вас есть объект с именем UserControl, который лежит в классе/метода, то можете. В вашем коде, вы этот объект передаете в метод, с которым вы там потом и работаете. Написать void addUserControl(UserControl) вы не можете, вам не позволит язык, ибо аргумент метода обязан иметь тип и название.

Я понял, я почитал про статичные методы и не статичные, я думал зачем ваще в скобках указывать юзерконтроль как класс, если могу в коде написать его класс и методы, оказывается просто нужно)

1-2 года как хобби, я уроки особо не смотрел, гуглил каждую функцию и все

в общем смысле функция в теории информации - это не совсем мат.функция, потому что мат.функция возвращает значение [этой самой функции], но иногда это не нужно, и функция ничего не возвращает [и это противоречит мат.функции], и в программировании это называется процедурой, или процедурной функцией

на самом деле, всё что вы делаете в вашем коде - это смыслом ближе к мат.оператору, а не к мат.функции, т.е. вы задаёте некоторую операцию кодом, эта операция и исполняется, т.е. есть некоторый объект и вы применяете к объекту операцию [или набор операций]

в математике вы передаёте аргумент в функцию, а в C# существует система типов, собственно C# - это и есть система типов [строго типизированные множества и строго типизированные отображения этих множеств], т.е. аргумент должен быть типизирован, и получается так, что вы пользуете не функцию а процедуру, в которую закидываете типизированный аргумент, и эта процедура описывает оператор [набор операций] - вот это вы делаете в вашем коде

Как я понял, речь идет о строчке
private void addUserControl(UserControl userControl)

Здесь UserControl это тип, а userControl это имя аргумента.
Например если бы вы принимали в метод число, было бы
private void MyMethod(int number)

Где int - тип, number - имя аргумента.
Чтобы не не повторяться, вы можете переименовать аргумент, например так
private void addUserControl(UserControl control)
{
    control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    PanelContainer.Controls.Clear();
    PanelContainer.Controls.Add(control);
    control.BringToFront();
}

Ну или как угодно его назвать можете, лишь бы код понятным оставался.
Кстати, названия методов в C# принято писать с большой буквы, должно быть AddUserControl.

Ага, а разве так нельзя? UserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

то есть сразу ссылаться на класс

@OfficialKronix нельзя. Есть свойства статические и свойства экземпляра, изучите разницу. Основы основ ООП.

там типо для нестатичных, они нужны если мы делаем несколько копий одного и того же

но ведь если я буду каждый раз склоняться сразу на класс, то разница не меняется

@OfficialKronix не понимаю вас, видимо потому что вы не особо пока разобрались что есть что. Попробуйте уделить немного времени и посмотреть уроки, с которых я сам начинал, многое станет понятнее.

Статический метод принадлежит классу, а нестатический метод принадлежит объекту класса. Статические методы полезны, если у вас есть только один экземпляр, в котором вы собираетесь использовать этот метод, и вам не нужны несколько копий (объектов). Нестатические методы используются, если вы собираетесь использовать свой метод для создания нескольких копий.

я расписал точнее

@OfficialKronix не далеко от правды, но назначение статики немного другое и редко зависит от количества требуемых копий. Но логически верно. Как новичку скажу, что статику лучше стараться не использовать до тех пор, пока вы не поймёте, когда она реально нужна. Бездумное использование статики может привести к нехорошему коду, который придется переписывать.

Спасибо, а вы не знаете, как можно exe  с .dll библиотеками связать?

@OfficialKronix новый вопрос лучше задавать отдельно. Библиотеки разные бывают, и не со всеми можно связаться. Управляемые можно как ссылки (референсы) в проект добавлять или загружать как сборки (assembly), неуправляемые через interop [DllImport]. Там много нюансов, тема обширная.
